# How to buy difficult-to-find electronic parts?

Tags: rf, filter, buying

A RF receiver project I'm working on calls for a [very specific](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9599/where-to-buy-saw-filters-in-low-quantity) SAW bandpass filter. I've checked all the usual sources here in the US (Jameco, Mouser, Digikey, Newark, etc) without success. What I'm finding is that the part I'm looking for is highly specialized and thus difficult to find anyone that sells them in low, hobbyist quantities.

What are some approaches for buying difficult-to-find parts in low quantities?

Comment: I am currently working on a project that uses a SAW filter. We are having to fab it ourselves. Not much help for you, but could be an option. They aren't overly difficult to make, but does take some thought.

Comment: What about trying to find other companies that are using the components in a mass produced product, they may be able to help out?

Answer (score 6):

Go to the manufacturer's website, find their list of franchised distributors and talk to them. However don't be surprised if you have to buy a whole reel/tube/tray and wait a few weeks, but you might be lucky and find someone with stock. You may be able to get small qtys as samples from the manufacturer or distributors. 
However there are many parts that you just can't buy in small quantities.

Answer (score 2):

Suppliers may be prepared to provide the name of customers who have purchased the part in quantity. Sometimes they may be willing to pass on your name to a buyer if the identity is confidential. I've only done this very occasionally and long long ago but it can be successful.